# Extraction of value from Chrome local storage not assigning the value to local variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am  creating a Chrome extension using React. During login I store the username and for some other operation I need to extract it inside the `background.js` file whose contents are below:

```
/* globals chrome */

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        let username;
        if (request.data.type == "SENDTRANSACTION") {
            chrome.storage.sync.get(['username'], (response) => {
                    console.log(response.username)
                    username = response.username // This is not being set on first invocation
            });
            console.log(username);
            sendResponse({message: "Sent values to Server"});
        }
    });
```

The value of `username` is `undefined`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Made a few edits. Its always `undefined`

Comment: Do you set `username` with `chrome.storage.sync.set`

Comment: Where are you logging (console.log) or using the variable `username`? Note that since `username` is defined (ie. `let username;`) in the function `function(request, sender, sendResponse) { ... }`, it will only be accessible within that specific function. Otherwise, you can expect it to return `undefined`

Comment: @Samleo i am checking it where i have written `//Some operations here`

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ yes i have set the username using that in another part of the application,

Comment: You see in console `response.username` is `undefined` or `username` is `undefined` ?

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ `username` is undefined. response.username has the relevant value.

Comment: Check my answer, call back don't run when you call `chrome.storage.sync.get`, it need time, so `console.log(username);` run before `console.log(response.username)`, sorry if you don't understand me(my english is bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    let username;
    if (request.data.type == "SENDTRANSACTION") {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['username'], (response)=>{
            username = response.username
            // This is not being set on first invocation

            console.log(username);
            sendResponse({
                message: "Sent values to Server"
            });
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

`chrome.storage.sync.get` need time to load data from storage, so your `sendResponse` before callback run (set `username = response.username`)

Check [runtime#event-onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, **unless you return true** from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously

Comment: this solution fixed what i was facing here. but the `message` from sendResponse was being checked in the callback of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` (this is the method that invoked this particular function with request.data.type = "SENDTRANSACTION" ) and now that is `undefined`

Comment: Can you tell me what is `that` (in `now that is undefined`) ?

Comment: this was the method which called the method in the question ^^.
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: event.data}, (response) => {
    console.log("ContentScript: response from background script::", response.message);
 });`


`response.message` is undefined after I moved `sendResponse` in the callback. I am not sure if I am clear enough. Please tell me if you need more details.

Comment: yes. `sendResponse` sent back some value (`Sent values to server`), now that value is undefined in the callback of the caller function.

Comment: Try add `return true;` after call `chrome.storage.sync.get`